# Page Not Found django

Tags: python, django

Why is this happening? I do everything according to the instructions. I study.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views 
urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^$',views.main,name="main"),
    url(r'^post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
# Create your views here.

def post_detail(request,id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'main/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

What to do? Even instead of id put pk, but nothing helps.

[image]

Comment: Post your main urls.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman main function is work, but i write "localhost:8000/post/2/" nothing changes.  [link on screenshot](http://prntscr.com/h9gjk0)

Comment: Does post with id 2 exist?

Comment: @MohammadMustaqeem [id4(does not exist)](https://prnt.sc/h9gnz1)  , [id3](https://prnt.sc/h9gome)

Comment: Are you sure that you have a post with `id` of 1 in your database?? Can you check that in your admin page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your urls.py file should work (it worked for me) but you should end this url with $ to prevent matching urls with something after product id with this view.

```
url(r'^post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

You can use pdb in `post_detail` method to check is called:

```
def post_detail(request,id):
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'main/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

If method is called that execution should stop on `pdb.set_trace()` line. You can resume it with pressing 'c' and ENTER.
pdb is very useful and you should use it first when you have a problem. (Mode details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

If method is called that it should be problem with lack of post with given id, Otherwise you should make sure that `ROOT_URLCONF` from settings are referencing this module.

To check is post with this id existing:

Try this command in django shell:

```
Post.objects.get(pk=1)
```

if it returns

```
Post.DoesNotExist
```

than you need to create this post using:

```
Post.objects.create(pk=1, **some_values)
```

Comment: I did it, but nothing has changed. post with id 4 exists, but the link does not work   [id 4](https://prnt.sc/h9gwtq) . I'm using python3

Comment: In this picture i see that page for post with id = 4 is correctly rendered. What is not ok with it?

Comment: because you are in pdb breakpoint. go to command line press c and enter to resume. than remove import pdb and  ipdb.set_trace lines. pdb is for detecting what exactly fails. when you fix your problem you should remove all pdb.set_trace() lines. please read the documentation of pdb it is very useful for solving many problems with your python cpde